# Installing Windoze again alongside Lubuntu?

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows-7

I have an old Gateway LT27 laptop with Lubuntu 18.4.04 on it, that I put on a few years ago.  I'm fairly new to Linux/Ubuntu.  I've tried to connect Boss BR 600 recorder software, to my Boss Recorder, via Virtualbox on my Linux and Lubuntu machines, to no avail.  So, I'm putting Windows 7 on the Lubuntu machine to see if the software will Connect with my Boss recorder.

I tried to put Windoze 7 via Live USB.  It was loading nicely, then it told me I needed an NTFS Partion to install it.  So, I partioned the drive with a Live USB version of Kali(Ubuntu, when I did the original install I had it only with 1 partion).  So, now I approx 30 gb for lubuntu, and 130 GB (NTFS) that I've set aside for Windoze, along with a boot flag.

When I try and install Windoze now, with the Live USB, it doesn't even go into booting, it just gives me a 
"Check Cable Connection!
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel PXE M0F"
Then goes onto load Lubuntu!

The only thing I notice in Disk(Lubuntu) says that the NTFS drive is "Unmounted"

Do I need to mount this drive.

If it's easier, I can uninstall ubuntu, and install windows.  This is my 2nd PC, that I don't use very much.

Thanks in advance for help.
Ralph

Comment: There is always a way.  BUT that could cost days. If you want the cleanest way then you need to scrub the disk.  Make a 100 MB boot FAT 32 partition first and then the other partitions.  THEN install Windows. When that is done and updated. Then install your buntu.

Comment: Thank you.  Easiest way, I guess by using a Ubuntu Live on USB again, with gparted?

Comment: I think that it the easiest.  Lots of work but will be the most robust in the future.

Comment: Lots of work?  Just deleting a partition?

Comment: I meant starting from scratch.  Setting up the boot partition. Installing Windows.  Then installing Lubuntu.